# Little snitch and different network profiles

Tags: network, firewall, administrator

Is there any way to have different "little snitch" rules set for different networking profiles ?
like for HOME one rule list
for WORK another etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little Snitch will tell you and allow you to do the following:

- Informs you when an app or process trys to access "stuff" over the network
- Allows you to set up and block communication by one of more of the following:

  - Protocol
  - Port
  - App or Process
  - destination address, IP address, or hostname, and more.

Unfortunately what it does not allow you to do is filter or create rules based on the "Location" or the current connection name as defined in OS X Network preferences (with the exception of "Local Network")

Other Firewall Software may allow you to do this, but this is a limitation of Little Snitch.

Littel Snitch 3 is now in preview mode, one among the new features is "Profiles" defined as follows:

> Profiles
>
> With Little Snitch 3, rules can optionally be arranged in separate profiles like “Home”, “Office” or “Internet Cafe”. Rules that are assigned to a particular profile are only effective if that profile is active. The active profile can be chosen conveniently from the status menu.
>
> This allows you to quickly switch between different sets of rules depending if you are at home, at the office or connected to a public network.

Comment: it is really too bad :( and do you know any suitable firewall similar little snitch (design, lightweight etc) but with described functionality ?

Comment: so in Apple world there is no any firewall with matching my requirement ? nice :) how it is possible in case when everyone is so mobile, unbelievable ;( switching between users it's not good solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Little Snitch 4.1.3, you can have a different profile that is connected to different wifi networks

Comment: While this might technically be a correct answer, you're answering a question that's 6 years old.  The versions will be different from the original question and the ways to perform the steps will be different.  Your answer can be made much better by adding additional info, such as how to create a different profile and set the rules per network.  - From Review.

Comment: You're basically saying "don't necro threads." This isn't a forum, and this forum rat nonsense is inappropriate to a Stack Exchange site. If the answer changed, a new answer should be created, rather than duplicating questions.